# Apache Spark: A Task failed with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.copyOverlappingLong

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

A Task failed with `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at `com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.copyOverlappingLong`.
And the whole job was terminated after repeated task failures.

It ran without any problem several days ago.

Currently we suspect that the cluster is malfunctioning, since from yesterday Ambari (Hortonworks Hadoop cluster manager) reports corrupted blocks, node problems etc.
That problems persist even after complete cluster re-installation. (Our cluster is small – only has 3 data nodes) So, maybe it is a hardware problem.

Could it be a network problem? Or disk?

Detailed log is as follows:

```
14/07/10 16:33:58 INFO Main: Initializing context
--args is deprecated. Use --arg instead.
14/07/10 16:34:04 INFO Main: Processing
14/07/10 16:37:32 ERROR YarnClientClusterScheduler: Lost executor 4 on cluster04: remote Akka client disassociated
14/07/10 16:37:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 304 (task 1.0:304)
14/07/10 16:37:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 303 (task 1.0:303)
14/07/10 16:52:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 1614 (task 0.0:359)
14/07/10 16:52:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65535
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.copyOverlappingLong(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:221)
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.decodeChunk(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:117)
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.decodeChunk(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:66)
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFInputStream.readyBuffer(LZFInputStream.java:339)
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFInputStream.read(LZFInputStream.java:169)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2310)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2323)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3063)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:63)
           at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$1.getNext(Serializer.scala:125)
           at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:71)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
           at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:30)
           at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
           at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:58)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKey$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:107)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKey$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:106)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:582)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:582)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedValuesRDD.compute(MappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedValuesRDD.compute(MappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
14/07/10 16:52:45 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 1617 (task 0.0:359)
14/07/10 16:52:54 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 1620 (task 0.0:359)
14/07/10 16:52:54 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

14/07/10 16:52:56 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 1622 (task 0.0:359)
14/07/10 16:52:56 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65535
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.copyOverlappingLong(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:221)
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.decodeChunk(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:117)
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.decodeChunk(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:66)
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFInputStream.readyBuffer(LZFInputStream.java:339)
           at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFInputStream.read(LZFInputStream.java:169)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2310)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2323)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3063)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:63)
           at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$1.getNext(Serializer.scala:125)
           at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:71)
           at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
           at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:30)
           at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
           at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:58)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKey$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:107)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKey$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:106)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:582)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:582)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedValuesRDD.compute(MappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedValuesRDD.compute(MappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
14/07/10 16:52:56 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0.0:359 failed 4 times; aborting job
14/07/10 16:52:56 WARN TaskSetManager: Task 1599 was killed.
14/07/10 16:52:58 INFO Main: Clearing intermediate directory
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0:359 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Exception failure in TID 1622 on host cluster02: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65535
        com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.copyOverlappingLong(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:221)
        com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.decodeChunk(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:117)
        com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkDecoder.decodeChunk(UnsafeChunkDecoder.java:66)
        com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFInputStream.readyBuffer(LZFInputStream.java:339)
        com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFInputStream.read(LZFInputStream.java:169)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2310)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2323)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3063)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1638)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:63)
        org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$1.getNext(Serializer.scala:125)
        org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:71)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:30)
        org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:58)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKey$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:107)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKey$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:106)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:582)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:582)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedValuesRDD.compute(MappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedValuesRDD.compute(MappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Driver stacktrace:
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1033)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1017)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
           at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1207)
           at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
           at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
           at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65535` means that you you are trying to access an index that is not in the array, and that might be due to the Array Max Size or due to the fact that this index doesn't exist in your array

Comment: @eliasah Thanks, but maybe that is the result of a deeper problem. Please see my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was gone when I replaced the suspected data node and re-installed the cluster.

I suspect that the disk of that data node is malfunctioning, thus the data read from that disk is corrupt, and the decoder couldn't handle the invalid input data.